# Can you rely solely on security groups to securely restrict access to Publicly Accessible RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I am trying to balance convenience/cost vs security while setting up RDS and lambda. My ultimate goal is to make the architecture as simple and cheap as possible while keeping it secure.

I have a couple of basic requirements that gives me a headache trying to balance my options without significantly increasing cost and complexity:

1. (some) Lambdas needs to access the internet
2. I want to (sometimes) have direct access to the database

I could go the "best practices" route with a bastion host in a public subnet, private lambdas, lambdas with internet access and RDS all in separate private subnets and security groups and using a NAT Gateway for lambdas to communicate out. This adds a lot of cost and moving parts with a NAT Gateway and a bastion host.

As a "step-down" in cost and complexity that is (hopefully) greater than the loss of security, I am considering the following:

1. Put all lambdas in a private subnet. For the lambdas that needs access to the internet, they can directly invoke a separate lambda that lives outside the VPC for accessing the public internet. Can I do something simple to not pay for 2x the idle time while waiting for a response here?
2. To solve the bastion host I have experimented with putting RDS in a public subnet and setting it to Publicly Accessible, but still only allowing ingress from the private lambda security group. I can then add my IP to the security group and restrict external ingress to my IP only. Can I trust security groups alone to be secure enough here, assuming I only allow my specific IP when I actually need it? Or do you actually need to use private subnets as well to have any hope of security?

I haven't really seen this suggested anywhere, which is why I am asking here - what am I missing that makes this a horrible idea?

Comment: The greatest cost in the "best practices" route will be RDS anyway. NAT gateway can be replaced with cheapest NAT instance if cost is the greatest concern. Cost for lambda will be minute compared to RDS. So the only contributor to cost is RDS. I assume you want RDS for its Multi-AZ and Read-Replica capabilities, automatic backups, etc? If not then host regular db on your own instance to cut cost to minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security Groups are **totally reliable** for protecting resources in a VPC.

However, some security professionals recommend "security in depth" by **adding multiple layers of security**. This way, if one layer was incorrectly configured, the resources would not be vulnerable. Thus, they would recommend using Security Groups *and* private subnets *and* limiting access to specific IP ranges *and* using multi-factor authentication, etc.

It is **always a trade-off** between your 'appetite for risk' vs cost and effort.

It appears that **cost is an overriding concern for you**, so you would be willing to go to some additional effort (using 2 Lambda functions) or reducing security (by not using private subnets). That's fine, since it is always a trade-off and that decision is up to you.